# CGContextShowTextAtPoint deprecated - what shall I use now?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

The following will be considered as deprecated in iOS 7:
CGContextSelectFont,
CGContextShowTextAtPoint.
What should I use instead?

Comment: All iOS beta API changes are under NDA and cannot be discussed here. This is something for the Apple developer forums.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `[yourString drawAtPoint:aPoint withAttributes:dictOfAttributes];`

Docs for that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:withAttributes:).

Or you could just add a `UILabel` to your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

//begin graphic context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

```
//get the context for coreGraphics
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[@"yourstring" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"  size:17]}];
//make image out of bitmap context
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```